# Difference between string.concat and the + operator in string concatenation

Tags: java, string-concatenation

(This question may be a duplicate but I really didn't understand the other answers)

You have the following code:

```
String str ="football";
str.concat(" game");
System.out.println(str); // it prints football
```

But with this code:

```
String str ="football";
str = str + " game";
System.out.println(str); // it prints football game
```

So what's the difference and what's happening exactly?

Comment: You didn't assign `str.concat(" game");` to a variable, so `str` still has its original value.

Comment: Strings are imutable, so you have to assing `str.concat(" game");` to a variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.concat(" game");` has the same meaning as `str + " game";`. If you don't assign the result back somewhere, it's lost. You need to do:

```
str = str.concat(" game");
```

Comment: So what happened exactly is the following? : str.concat(" game") created a new string object "football game" But it didn't change the str reference, and str still refer to "football"

Comment: @BaselQarabash yes

Answer (score 2):

The 'concat' function is immutable, so the result of it must be put in a variable. Use:

```
str = str.concat(" game");
```

Comment: Just a small thing: `String`s are imutable, not the `concat` function